# Orchard CMS and aspx based views in theme instead of razor?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm a die hard fan of aspx views over razor (cshtml) views. Is it possible to use aspx views in a Orchard theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment yes, but there is talk about cutting that support by default. I'd be curious to know what you find so appealing about aspx.

Comment: @Bertrand I think it's like asking why you might like C# over Java. They're kind of the same, but not really and you're probably more comfortable with one over the other. I started out with aspx and know all the tricks. My brain is a cup and I try not to let it spillith over with duplicate methodologies. From what I can tell, they both do the same thing. Why recreate and re-learn the wheel?

Comment: Yes, so it is supported right now but keep in mind that such support might disappear in a future version, maybe 2.0.